# Run Windows 7 virtual machine on SDHC card or share drive with Mac OS?

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, ssd, vmware-fusion, sd-card

Does anyone know if a VMware Fusion virtual machine of Windows 7 would run better on a class 6 SDHC card than it does sharing the disk with Mac OS?  Or if a single SSD drive would do better? I like to live in the Mac world for day-to-day things, but I also have a complete development environment set up in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the VM not using the same hard drive will help a bit, as long as the thing you're storing the VM on is about as as fast as a hard drive. According to Wikipedia, the SDHC class 6 card is capable of 6 MByte/s so that's not a good idea.  modern laptop drive is probably at least 50MB/s read and write speed.  A good consumer SSD will write about that fast and read even faster than it writes. It just depends on which SSD.